# Using Serilog for Blazor Server solution -> "IHostBuilder does not contain a definition for 'UseSerilog'

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, blazor, serilog

I am trying to implement Serilog for my Blazorserver project.

First and foremost, i follow the instructions as described in the link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/log-data-into-file-using-serilog-framework-in-blazor-server-app/.

In this instruction the following lines appear in the second code block:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)  
.UseSerilog()  
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>  
    {  
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();  
    });
```

Where the line .Useserilog() is **newly added**. The precompiler now throws the following error message:

```
"IHostBuilder does not contain a definition for 'UseSerilog'
```

I have added using Serilog and
using Serilog.Events in the Program.cs file (all "usings" are listed here):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding `using Serilog.Extensions.Hosting;`? You may need the [Serilog.Extensions.Hosting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Extensions.Hosting/) Nuget package too.

Comment: At least the precompiler does not throw an error anymore! Thanks alot, mate :)

Comment: Always mention which (versions of) packages you added.

Answer (score 2):

`UseSerilog` is an extension method in the `Serilog.Extensions.Hosting` namespace so you will need to import that:

```
using Serilog.Extensions.Hosting;
```

You may also need to add the [Serilog.Extensions.Hosting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Extensions.Hosting/) Nuget package.

Comment: solved it, thanks!